# App crash on Android 6.0 API 23 (but not on Android 9, API 28)

Tags: java, android

So i use two different emulators for testing my little app. Strangly the Android 6.0 API 23 version recently started to crash when trying to open an activity from the app. I don't remember what I did :(

Here's the error message i get from "RUN". My guess is that has to something with the GUI? The post page on Stackoverflow only let me post so much of the error so i cut out much of it. Maybe this part is important "   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:" Anyone know what is happening here?

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.dex, PID: 24065
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dex/com.example.dex.Activity2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #517: Binary XML file line #517: Error inflating class ImageButton
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #517: Binary XML file line #517: Error inflating class ImageButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070082
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
            at 

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #517: Error inflating class ImageButton
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you expected, the source of your problem is in the last lines. When Android tries to inflate a layout which contains ImageButton, it does not find a resource. If this is on higher API-levels only, you might have a resource which is a subfolder like drawable-v24 only available for defined API-levels. The reason might also be that you are using a parameter or property that was added later.

Comment: Thanks Christian that was it! I had placed an image in drawable-v24. I only saw then when looking with "Finder"(MacOS). Android Studio told me that that image was located in /drawable